# How to keep the drop down list selected option same for next request using refresh header?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, http-request-parameters

While refreshing my web page automatically using

```
    response.setHeader("refresh","10;url=/SiteAvailabilityServlet");
```

It is taking the drop down list selected URL for the first time when I invoke manually taking correctly. But after 10 seconds while refreshing it is taking the drop down list selected value as **null** (I am not changing the option in the list.. it is same as the first time selected option). How to solve this issue?
Please help me.

I got one answer from stackoverflow as

```
response.setHeader("Refresh","10;url="+request.getContextPath+"/SiteAvailabilityServlet?ursel="+urlsel);
```

But where to use this *ursel*? In my JSP code?

How the servlet or JSP knows that the drop down list has **ursel** is the parameter while refreshing the web page after 10 seconds?